# [Erratic Robot] unable to launch this package!

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

I am looking to launch the erratic robot I downloaded from (Am I using the outdated package?)

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-erratic-robot
```

then execute:

```
roslaunch erratic_navigation_apps demo_2dnav_slam.launch
```

But I got the following errorS from gazebo:

```
 Error [parser.cc:712] XML Element[filename], child of element[mesh] not defined in SDF. Ignoring.[mesh]
    
    Error [parser.cc:703] Error reading element <mesh>
    
    Error [parser.cc:703] Error reading element <geometry>
    
    Error [parser.cc:703] Error reading element <collision>
    
    Error [parser.cc:703] Error reading element <link>
    
    Error [parser.cc:703] Error reading element <model>
    
    Error [parser.cc:703] Error reading element <world>
    
    Error [parser.cc:369] Unable to read element <sdf>
    
    Error:   Could not find the 'robot' element in the xml file
    
             at line 59 in /tmp/buildd/ros-groovy-urdfdom-0.2.7-0precise-20130326-0224/urdf_parser/src/model.cpp
    
    Error [parser_urdf.cc:1814] Unable to call parseURDF on robot model
    
    Warning [parser.cc:377] SDF has no <sdf> element in file[urdf file]
    
    Error [parser.cc:291] parse as old urdf model file failed.
    
    Error [Server.cc:253] Unable to read sdf file[/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/wg_collada.world]
    
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
    
    [gazebo-1] process has died [pid 19218, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo -u /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/wg_collada.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/dijia/.ros/log/1e527878-d52b-11e2-83e6-d0df9ada3503/gazebo-1.log].
    
    log file: /home/abc/.ros/log/1e527878-d52b-11e2-83e6-d0df9ada3503/gazebo-1*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65202/%5Berratic-robot%5D-unable-to-launch-this-package!/) by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2013-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to also parse the robot model and spawn it into gazebo . Try other launch files in the gazebo apps package. There should be a move_base launch file. If you have your own urdf file, you can use it instead.

---

Originally posted by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) with karma: 340 on 2013-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on 2013-12-16**:
Hi, could you provide some detailed advice on parsing the robot model and spawn it into gazebo? For instance, in which package? how to parse the robot model? thanks!

**Comment by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on 2013-12-17**:
Do you have a xacro file and a urdf model for your own robot? In your launch file you have to include the robot description and joint state publisher. Check gazebo tutorials on how to build your own model and to spawn it in the gazebo. Its pretty straight forward if you understood tf.